# Is it possible to dynamically resize emc lun which is using powerpath

Tags: storage, emc, lun, powerpath

*I have the below mount which is coming from EMC storage and uses powerpath drivers .Now Storage has resized this to 1.5 TB , is it possible to resize this in host without any downtime .

```
[root@xxxxxxx emcpowera]# powermt display dev=emcpowera

Pseudo name=emcpowera
VNX ID=xxxxxx
 [xxxxxxx_122014]

Logical device ID=dsdsdsdsdsdsds11 [xxxxxx
_122014_orcl_bkup]

state=alive; policy=CLAROpt; queued-IOs=0


******************


[root@xxxxemcpowera]# df -hP /orcl_bkup

Filesystem                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/vg_orcl_bkup-lv_orcl_bkup  886G  779G   99G  89% /orcl_bkup

************************
[root@xxxxxxx emcpowera]# pvs | grep -i powera

 /dev/emcpowera vg_orcl_bkup     lvm2 a--  900.00g     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing you need to do after you resized the luns in your storage is, `echo 1 > /sys/block/<subpath>/device/rescan` for every subpath of `emcpowera`

Now you need to tell to your server, the size of `/dev/emcpowera` has changed, use `sfdisk -R /dev/emcpowera`

If you are using `/dev/emcpowera` as physical volume, use `pvresize /dev/emcpowera`, after this you can resize your logical volume and the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is some sort of linux, you can follow a [procedure](http://www.standalone-sysadmin.com/blog/2009/05/resizing-storage-luns-in-linux-on-the-fly/) to rescan the drive, see the new space, and increase the filesystem. It might vary from distro to distro, though, so you might need to look at the documentation.